# Entity Framework and deferred execution on lazy loaded ICollection

Tags: entity-framework-4, deferred-execution

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 and I have a one to many relationship.

When I query the lazy loaded `ICollection<T>` on the one side of the relationship the whole recordset is returned and it doesn't defer the execution like when I'm querying direct from the Repository `IQueryable` interface.

Is there any way to make this use deferred execution so I can do a query like

```
Model.Childs.Where(x => !x.Deleted.HasValue).Skip(10).Take(5);
```

Thanks in advance,

Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is principle of lazy loading in EF. Your navigation property is defined in your code and any LINQ query defined on that property is LINQ-to-Objects - it is not translated to SQL. Lazy loading always loads whole collection (as well as eager loading). When you query your repository you are querying IQueryable and using LINQ-to-Entities which is translated to SQL.

As workaround use explicit loading:

```
dbContext.Entry(Model).Collection(m => m.Childs)
                      .Query()
                      .Where(c => !c.Deleted.HasValue)
                      .Skip(10)
                      .Take(5)
                      .Load();
```